# Create a threads and execute a procedure on parallel with Tcl

Tags: multithreading, tcl

I am trying to execute one procedure on an auxiliary thread while the rest of my code will be executed in parallel. I have this small example:

```
set thread_loadmaterials [thread::create]

thread::send -async $thread_loadmaterials [list wa "hola from thread_loadmaterials"]
thread::send -async [thread::id] [list wa "hola from thread::id"]
```

NOTE: The created thread, checked by thread::exists procedure, exists.
The thread_loadmaterials has the created thread id and it's a different id than the active
thread ([thread::id]).

To my surprise, the thread identified by [thread::id] is showing the message but the thread that I create, don't do anything.
If someone can help me to understand it, I will be a lot grateful.

Comment: What's the `wa` command? Is it defined in the new thread?

Comment: The wa command is like a puts, to show the message on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

The man page on [`thread::send -async`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/ThreadCmd/thread.html#M17) says:

> The target thread must enter it's event loop in order to receive
> scripts sent via this command. [...] Threads can enter the event loop
> explicitly by calling thread::wait or any other relevant Tcl/Tk
> command, like update, vwait,

You never have the main thread (as identified by `thread::id`) in your script enter the event loop, e.g., by calling `vwait`

That said, there is no real need of `thread::send`'ing to the self, and here main thread.